# How to check if user is logged into Reddit

Tags: javascript, reddit, snoocore

I am trying to use the Snoocore library in order to access the Reddit API.

I want to occasionally do a check to see whether a user is logged into Reddit. These checks will determine whether they have certain form elements (for example, an add comment box).

I am using the standard cookie login (soon to be deprecated and I'll switch before the end date of support but I was having some issues and don't want to switch just yet)

Here's the basic code from the example:

```
var reddit = new Snoocore({
    userAgent: 'logonTest',
    login: { username: 'yourUsername', password: 'yourPassword' }
});

var loginPromise = reddit.login();
```

Whenever I do a console.log() of loginPromise, it tells me that it is fulfilled (regardless of whether my credentials are correct or not) and resolved is always equal to true.

How do I do a quick check to determine if the user is logged in, without ruining the user experience for users with incorrect credentials or no credentials?

Would I do something like an async callback?

```
var loginPromise = reddit.login({
    username: 'yourUsername',
    password: 'yourPasswd'
}).then(function(result) {
    callBack(result)
});
```

Not quite sure how to do a simple login check.

If I have to switch to OAuth to get this, I am willing to do so, but I'd really prefer to hold off on that for a couple of months.

Comment: Instead of trying to do credential sniffing, why not just test for whether there's a user comment box where there would be one, and if it doesn't exist, don't do what you'd otherwise do?

Comment: Is that data that is included with the Reddit API? Currently I was adding the comment boxes.

Comment: ah, in that sense. I'd say ask on https://github.com/trevorsenior/snoocore first.